# Seq.range[Double] : Could not find implicit value for evidence parameter

Tags: scala

```
Seq.range[Double](.0, 1.0 + step, step).foreach(current_degree_of_freedom => { ... }
```

(with `step` a `Double`).

The full error is :

> Error:(39, 26) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of
>   type Integral[Double]
>           Seq.range[Double](.0, 1.0 + step, step).foreach(current_degree_of_freedom => {

I have read the ScalaDoc ( http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Seq$.html#rangeT(implicitevidence$2:Integral[T]):CC[T] ), the problem comes from the 2nd curryied list of parameter.

But I don't understand the error... I thought it could be due to the absence of `[Double]` just after `Seq.range`, so I wrote it but it didn't solve the problem...

Anyone can explain me the problem please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass in `Double` values to the `range` method, the compiler will look for an implicit `Integral[Double]`. Apparently you're not providing this implicit value, hence the error. To make the compiler happy, add an implicit `Integral[Double]`:

```
implicit val integralD = scala.math.Numeric.DoubleAsIfIntegral

val range = Seq.range(0.0, 1.2, 0.2)
// List(0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6000000000000001, 0.8, 1.0)
```

Comment: Thank you ! Would it be possible to explain to me what is an `Integral` ? Is it the mathematical integration ? By the way, why should I add/provite this implicit value of type `Integral[Double]`, if it's censed to be ... "implicit" ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need Seq? Scala has a very rich type structure.

Your type is probably NumericRange and there is a natural way to generate the sequence of numbers you want to work with. Check the result type of this

```
val mynumrange = 0.0 to 1.0 by step
```

Comment: Is it normal if you had written `.1` instead of `0` ?

Comment: Do you mean what literals are understood for floating point numbers representation? Yes, you can use 0.1 or .1 . It is documented in the lexical syntax of language spec. See examples in https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#floating-point-literals

Comment: oh, I see now, it was a typo, use 0 instead of 0.1 as the starting point. Once I find out how to edit post I will correct it. Thanks for the comment